# Looking for reference of well-built XHTML/CSS/JSP2 norms/best practices

Tags: css, jsp, xhtml

My task is to compile a norm / best practices especially for XHTML and CSS.

Would somebody have some good references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [This is a good introduction on writing sane XHTML code.](http://www.graphicrating.com/2008/11/29/xhtml-best-practices/)
- Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275631/html-head-best-practices) on best practices for the `<head>` tag.
- Reading the XHTML [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) is a great way to get a lot of best practices.
- Internationalization and language coding are also best practices, see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/).

As your question hints at - there is not one place to find the set-in-stone best practices, but rather a multitude of places on the net that can give you a few jewels of wisdom. Also, nothing beats real experience and looking at other peoples code. I learned a lot from looking at many free/open source XHTML templates - like [these](http://www.oswd.org/).

Comment: I understand that everything is not written in marble. I therefore chose your solution, that is to compile pieces of advices. Unfortunately I have to write a documentation, not to learn, so I cannot just gain wisdom and do things the right way :-) Thank you alot.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the technology used to generate XHTML and CSS, I'd recommend these XHTML/CSS resources ...

- [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com)
- [SitePoint CSS](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css)
- [Opera Developer Articles](http://dev.opera.com/articles/)

Comment: Thank you, your first link helped me a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look [creating sexy stylesheets](http://thinkvitamin.com/features/design/creating-sexy-stylesheets), [xhtml.com](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/) and [W3 Schools](http://w3schools.com).