# AJAX not always working

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi i am new and i love this site

I am learning javascript and so far i have done a lot of tutorials but i can't make ajax work.

I saw this on W3school

```
   var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Now i changed one line to

`xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.php?day="+document.getElementById("day").value,true);`

It should read info based on a day instead of all of the days.

Sometimes the page is empty, nothing happens, sometimes it works and everything is there.

To reproduce you can just hit F5 like 3 times in a row, it will fail at least once.

Please help me save the last bits of hair i still have !

Comment: Your problem rings a bell, i bet you have that code immediately inside <script> blocks right? no onload function i mean...
possible duplicate, i suggest searching the site before posting

Comment: yes how should i do it then? sorry i got confused

Comment: @Karmen Scripts within `<script>` blocks are immediately executed when `</script>` is encountered. When it's placed before `<body>`, the element with ID "day" may not exist (yet). To get it to work, defer the execution. Either by using `window.onload = function(){/*your code here*/};`, or by moving `<script>...</script>` to after the `<.. id="day">` element.

Comment: check this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190890/order-of-tags-in-head-head

the second answer has some information regarding the order in which scripts are placed, not immediately relevant to the problem you are having here but it should help you not make many mistakes later on

Comment: thanks you are really helpful, since no one else answer i will mark your answer as helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the script loading too fast that the "day" element is not there yet.

To fix you can simply add an event handler to wait for the document to load.

You can do this like that : `document.addEventListener("load", functionName, false);` and then create a function that will hold the code you pasted here.

The function will be called at the appropriate time and it should work.

Other than that, i would recommend using libraries like jQuery or MooTools as it makes it easier for your code to run across many browsers. In your code, you are checking to see which browser the user has to create the request..

With jquery you can do all your code with a single line of code like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   // Wait for the document to load
    $.get("http://www.website.com?day="+$("#day").val());   // $.get will create an ajax, $("#day") is equivalent to getting an element by Id
});
```

You can learn more at http://www.jquery.com

Comment: @Karmen Warning: jQuery looks easy, but do **not** start with it until you understand how JavaScript and DOM works. Otherwise, you'll become one of these jQuery developers who does not know how to write something simple without jQuery. A greate place to learn JavaScript is **not** W3Schools, because of the [questionable reliability](httP;//w3fools.com/). Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/ for the #1 documentation on JavaScript, CSS, HTML and related technology.

Comment: true, i agree mozilla has the best JS and CSS documentation, the most structured too, i've never used it for html but it's definitely better than w3schools, @RobW nice link for the intervention :D

Answer (score 0):

@Karmen, didn't see your complete code, so not sure the real reason it might fail.
For my test page at http://wp89.com/test/ajax/
I press F5 to refresh more than 10 times, but no failure.

Please remember that you need to wait for the page to load completely every time as the connection may be slow.